# Perl can't find file

Tags: perl

I am a relatively infrequent user of Perl. I have written a script that takes two input files with the same name but different extensions, processes them and outputs a third file. It works when I specify the  name of the file, but I want it to search for all relevant files in a directory and process all of them. However, when I do this it keeps saying there is no such file or directory - even though I'm sure there is. I've looked at all the relevant pages on this site and tried the suggestions there, but it still doesn't work. I'm stumped.

Here is the code, missing the processing of the files themselves, as that is long and not relevant.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#specify single file - works when this is not commented and the loops below are
#my $file = "BE_Read01_f2-2";
#on a Mac
my $dir = "/Users/sashacalhoun/Documents/supervision/tariq/Syllables";
opendir(my $dh, $dir);
while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
    if($file=~s/(.+-CV)\.TextGrid/$1/) {
        print "$file\n";
        open(my $syl, "<", "$dir/${file}.par");
        while(my $line=<$syl>) {
            #processes this file - not included
        }
        close($syl);

        my $gridfile = "$file-CV.TextGrid";
        my $outfile =  "$file-syl.TextGrid";

        open(my $grid, "<", $gridfile);
        open(my $out, ">", $outfile);

        while(my $line=<$grid>) {
            print $out $line;
            # other processing of this file
        }

        close($grid);
        close($out);
    }
}
```

It says: `Can't open '/Users/sashacalhoun/Documents/supervision/tariq/Syllables/BE_Read01_f2-1-CV.par' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at ./get_syl.pl line 36`

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that exists? Does a `-e` test work?

Comment: It would be a better test if your hard-coded file name was `BE_Read01_f2-1-CV.TextGrid`. See if that works with your `while` loop removed. By the way, you are adding a second `-CV` to your file name when you define `$gridfile`. Your substitution removes `.TextGrid` from the end, and you put back `-CV.TextGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, it is apparent that the line causing the error is this line:

```
open(my $syl, "<", "$dir/${file}.par");
```

> it keeps saying there is no such file or directory - even though I'm sure there is.

You can prove to yourself that no such file exists by copying the path in the error message:

> Can't open
>   '**/Users/sashacalhoun/Documents/supervision/tariq/Syllables/BE_Read01_f2-1-CV.par**'
>   for reading: 'No such file or directory' at ./get_syl.pl line 36

and doing this:

```
$ ls /Users/sashacalhoun/Documents/supervision/tariq/Syllables/BE_Read01_f2-1-CV.par
```

And, instead of constructing paths yourself, you should consider using File::Spec, etc.:

```
use File::Spec::Functions;

my $path = catfile $dirname, $fname;
```

And, you should probably check whether the filename is a file or directory before constructing your path:

```
if (-f $path -r $path) { #then it's a file that is readable...
   #Here you might want to skip files whose names start with a '.', i.e. hidden files

}
```

And, your debugging print statement should be this:

```
my $path = "$dir/$file.par";
print "$path\n";

open(my $syl, "<", "$path.par");
```

By the way, if you don't like typing \n after every print statement, you can use say():

```
say "After printing this text, perl automatically adds a '\n' to the end of the output";
```

You do have to employ a use statement for say() to work, e.g.

```
use 5.010;
```

<strike>And, you should add a die() clause to your opendir()/open() statements:</strike>

opendir(my $DIR, $dir) 
    or die "Couldn't open $dir: $!";

Comment: He does not need to add `die` statements, he is using `autodie`.

Comment: Hi - thanks very much for your quick response. I realised after reading your suggestions that I had the "-CV" part of the file extension in the wrong place... it's working now! Thank you also for the other suggestions about how to run it without specifying the directory.